# Win 10 search bar ignores default browser

Tags: windows-10, browser, default-settings

I am trying to change the browser that opens when performing Internet searches through the Win 10 search bar. I tried:

- changing default browser in "default apps" https://puu.sh/DrfB8/c6e6d98816.png changing this had no effect, it still uses Edge
- set defaults by app https://puu.sh/DrfTn/211d59a5a8.png changing this had no effect, it still uses Edge
- use the old control panel to set the default browser - it seems this has been removed as it redirects me to the above mentioned menu
- try a different browser - Vivaldi is based on chrome so I tried Firefox and it has the same problem

no matter what I do, Windows keeps using Edge instead of my preferred browser. How do i fix this?

Comment: You need third part app like `edge deflector` for that purpose .... You can't do that natively... | It is not recommended to do so... Thanks

Comment: @vaku that tool does exactly what i needed, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this cannot be done natively, but we can use [Edge deflector](https://github.com/da2x/EdgeDeflector) to force windows to use the selected default browser for all links that are hard coded to be opened in Edge.

As a cherry on top we can then use a browser add-on like [Chrometana](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrometana-redirect-bing/kaicbfmipfpfpjmlbpejaoaflfdnabnc) to redirect Bing searches to your favourite search engine.

Credits to @vaku for telling me about Edge deflector.

---

Github: [EdgeDeflector](https://github.com/da2x/EdgeDeflector)

> EdgeDeflector is a small helper application that intercepts URIs that
>   force-open web links in Microsoft Edge and redirects it to the
>   system’s default web browser. This allows you to use Windows features
>   like the Cortana assistant and built-in help links with the browser of
>   your choice instead of being forced to use Microsoft Edge. With
>   EdgeDeflector, you’re free to use Firefox, Google Chrome, or whatever
>   your favorite web browser might be!

---

Chrome Plugin: [Chrometana](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrometana-redirect-bing/kaicbfmipfpfpjmlbpejaoaflfdnabnc)

> Redirect all Bing (and therefore Cortana) searches to a search engine
>   of your choice!

Comment: Edge Deflector does not work any more.
See https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/microsoft-edge-protocol-competition.html
I thought there were huge anti-trust lawsuits against Microsoft to stop them enforcing the their own non-OS additional software through the OS (e.g. Windows Media Player).
Why are they breaking the law (and now legal precedent) again?
Awful company.

Comment: Sad coincidence I was just looking for this and it is no longer possible :(